# CL build throws cs0146 error, Visual studio does not, What am I missing

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to build a windows notification service for a web app using Cefsharp, NotificationManagerCompat.cs throws a [CS0146](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0146) error (Circular base class reference) when I use command line build, but in VS it is fine, I think it is something in my environment (like ms build version). Since this code comes from Microsofts UWP package.

I tried changing around the Toolsversion in the csproj file, but that did not fix the problem. Before this problem occurred I already had to rewrite several expression body definitions `=>` since those are not yet supported either by our build server.

```
public abstract class NotificationActivator : NotificationActivator.INotificationActivationCallback    //cs0146 here, between NotificationActivator and INotificationActivationCallback
{
    public void Activate(string appUserModelId, string invokedArgs, NOTIFICATION_USER_INPUT_DATA[] data, uint dataCount)
    {
        OnActivated(invokedArgs, new NotificationUserInput(data), appUserModelId);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will be called when the user clicks on a foreground or background activation on a toast. Parent app must implement this method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arguments">The arguments from the original notification. This is either the launch argument if the user clicked the body of your toast, or the arguments from a button on your toast.</param>
    /// <param name="userInput">Text and selection values that the user entered in your toast.</param>
    /// <param name="appUserModelId">Your AUMID.</param>
    public abstract void OnActivated(string arguments, NotificationUserInput userInput, string appUserModelId);

    // These are the new APIs for Windows 10

    #region NewAPIs

    [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential ), Serializable]
    public struct NOTIFICATION_USER_INPUT_DATA
    {
        [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )]
        public string Key;

        [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )]
        public string Value;
    }

    [ComImport,
     Guid( "53E31837-6600-4A81-9395-75CFFE746F94" ), ComVisible( true ),
     InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
    public interface INotificationActivationCallback
    {
        void Activate(
            [In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string appUserModelId,
            [In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string invokedArgs,
            [In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3 )] NOTIFICATION_USER_INPUT_DATA[] data,
            [In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] uint dataCount);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I expected this to build so I could test it, but when I try it throws a circular base class dependency error

Answer (score 0):

It is best to always make your projects use the same C# version as supported on your Build Server. Doing so will give the same limitations and the same compile errors locally, and 
not only on the Build server. Here is how to do that:

[image: Visual Studio how to switch csharp version]

Besides that, and without having tried it: it might help to make the `INotificationActivationCallback` not be nested inside the class.